# Running excel vba code on multiple files on Macintosh

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I have the following code I wrote in Excel:

```
    Sub Multiple()
    MyDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
        strPath = MyDir & ":"

        strFile = Dir(strPath, MacID("TEXT"))

        'Loop through each file in the folder
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
            If Right(strFile, 3) = "csv" Then
                Debug.Print strFile
                DoWork (strFile)
            End If

            strFile = Dir
        Loop
End Sub

Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
    With wb
        Range("E:E,K:K").Select
        Range("K1").Activate
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        ActiveSheet.Range("b1").End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)/1000"
        ActiveSheet.Range("b1").End(xlDown).Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)), Type:=xlFillDefault
        ActiveSheet.Range("e1").End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)"
        ActiveSheet.Range("e1").End(xlDown).Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is run the bottom `Sub DoWork()` which does some basic editing on an excel file on my macintosh on multiple files.
For that I wrote the uper `Sub Multiple()` which should eventually run the bottom Sub on multiple files.
The files type are CSV files.

The bottom code works perfect when running it individually on each Excel file.
However, the top code does not do the trick of running on all multiple files.

Anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

In your Multiple code, you are passing a string parameter (the filename) to DoWork, but DoWork is expecting you to pass a Workbook object.

You will need to join strPath and strFile together (in Windows that would be `strPath & "\" & strFile` - I assume it will be something similar on a Mac) and then open the Workbook.  I would suggest the following code should be used where you currently are just doing `DoWork (strFile)`:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\" & strFile)  ' Adjust to suit for Mac filename syntax
DoWork wb
wb.Save
wb.Close False
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Actually, the exception in my script before getting to this stage of the script.
It is shouting for an error when trying to run
strFile = Dir(strPath, MacID("TEXT"))

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Figured it out :-)

```
    Sub Multiple()

    Dim SecDir As String
    Dim MyDir As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook


    MyDir = "tlv-mpzyw:Users:lcohen:Google Drive:SQA:Projects:vbaBotRegression:"
    SecDir = "files:"
    strPath = MyDir & SecDir
    Debug.Print strPath
    strFile = Dir(strPath)

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    Do While Len(strPath) > 0
        If Right(strFile, 3) = "csv" Then
            Debug.Print strFile
            Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)
            Range("E:E,K:K").Select
            Range("K1").Activate
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            ActiveSheet.Range("b1").End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)/1000"
            ActiveSheet.Range("b1").End(xlDown).Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)), Type:=xlFillDefault
            ActiveSheet.Range("e1").End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)"
            ActiveSheet.Range("e1").End(xlDown).Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)), Type:=xlFillDefault
            wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If

        strFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Now I have another issue,
Am getting the following error message:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> 'TLV-MPZYW:USERS:LCOHEN:GOOGLE
>   DRIVE:SQA:PROJECTS:VBABOTREGRESSION:FILES:SAMPLES_MULTIPLE_FILTERS_QUERIES-STATISTICS.CSV'
>   could not be found.Check the spelling of the file name, and verify
>   that the file location is correct.
>
> If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently
>   used files on the File menu, make sure that the file has not been
>   renamed, moved, or deleted.

I am clueless at this point on what might be causing this issue.
As you can see in my code, I am printing the file name to verify that it indeed reads it correctly.

Anyone?????

Comment: One comment (but unrelated to your current error):  `Do While Len(strPath) > 0` - this will always be True - you probably want `Do While Len(strFile) > 0`